# Read $_GET value in checkout/cart page

Tags: onepage-checkout

When a payment fail I redirect the customer to a URL looks like below

http://exsample.com/checkout/cart?status=0&responcecode=91

in the page how can I read this `$_GET['responcecode']` value?

please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533936/magento-getparam-v-get

Answer (score 2):

you can get it with below code in magento

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('responcecode');
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the value by using $_GET['responcecode'] as well. Appreciate your help